# Conditionally add an element to a list by using Apply to delay the Sequence until evaluation

Tags: sequence

Could you explain the details for the following code?

```
foo[x_, y_] := {a, If[x === y, b, Sequence @@ {}]}
foo[s, s]
foo[s, t]
```

Output:

> ```
> {a,b}
> {a}
> ```

Why isn't the output as follows?

> ```
> {a,b}
> {a,}
> ```

Comment: If you want `{a,}` as the result you could use `Null` instead of `Sequence @@ {}` in your `If` statement.

Comment: @JasonB Yes. I know it. Thanks.

Comment: Since `Sequence @@ {} === Nothing` evaluates to `True`, the definition is equivalent to `foo[x_, y_] := {a, If[x === y, b, Nothing]}`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank  you very much. A good explanation!

Comment: @BobHanlon I am actually quite surprised that `Sequence[] === Nothing` evaluates to `True`, since these are not structurally equivalent. In particular, for a generic head `h`, this will give `False`: `h[Sequence[]] === h[Nothing]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - In looking at it closely using `Trace`, the reason that `Sequence[] === Nothing` evaluates to `True` is that `SameQ[Sequence[], Nothing]` evaluates to `SameQ[Nothing]` and `SameQ` with any single argument evaluates to `True`, e.g., `SameQ[2] == SameQ[a] == True` is `True`. I would have expected `SameQ` to complain if given a single argument.

Comment: @BobHanlon Indeed, I should've figured that out :) Thanks. I guess I am getting out of shape...Not sure what the rationale was behind this semantics of `SameQ`, I agree with you in that I would also expect it to complain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Summary**

The behaviour we see is a consequence of the way `Sequence[]` expressions are processed.  They are only expanded when they are explicitly present as arguments to a function.  In the case at hand, `Sequence@@{}` only takes such a form after evaluation.  But `If` has the attribute `HoldRest` so that evaluation does not take place until after the argument list has already been assembled and the `If` function invoked.

**Details**

We start from the observation that the following three expressions give differing results:

```
{a, If[1==2, unused]} // InputForm
(* {a, Null} *)

{a, If[1==2, unused, Sequence[]]} // InputForm
(* {a, Null} *)

{a, If[1==2, unused, Sequence@@{}]} // InputForm
(* {a} *)
```

**If[1==2, unused] -> Null**

The first result is explained by the following [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) for `If`:

> If[*condition*, *t*] gives Null if condition evaluates to False.

Thus:

```
If[1==2, unused] // InputForm
(* Null *)

{a, If[1==2, unused]} // InputForm
(* {a, Null} *)
```

**If[1==2, unused, Sequence[]] -> Null**

The second result is a consequence of the attributes of `If`:

```
Attributes[If]
(* {HoldRest, Protected} *)
```

`If` does *not* have the attribute `SequenceHold` so prior to evaluation any explicit appearances of arguments with the head `Sequence` will be spliced into the argument list.  `Sequence` expansion is independent of evaluation, so it occurs despite the presence of `HoldRest` which inhibits evaluation of the second and third arguments.

In this case, an empty sequence is spliced in so the net result is the same as the first example (i.e. as if `If` were invoked with only two arguments:

```
If[1==2, unused, Sequence[]] // InputForm
(* Null *)

{a, If[1==2, unused, Sequence[]]} // InputForm
(* {a, Null} *)
```

**If[1==2, unused, Sequence@@{}] -> Sequence[]**

The argument `Sequence@@{}` is not evaluated when it is passed to `If` due to the presence of the `HoldRest` attribute.  This means that the head of the argument expression is actually `Apply`, not `Sequence`:

```
Head[Unevaluated[Sequence@@{}]]
(* Apply *)
```

Since the head is not explicitly `Sequence`, it does not get spliced into the argument list and so the `If` expression remains in three-argument form instead of two-argument form.  Since the condition is false the third argument `Sequence@@{}` is evaluated to `Sequence[]` and returned:

```
If[1==2, unused, Sequence@@{}] // InputForm
(* Sequence[] *)

{a, If[1==2, unused, Sequence@@{}]} // InputForm
(* {a} *)
```

In that last expression the result is notionally `{a, Sequence[]}`.  But since the second argument to `List` is explicitly `Sequence[]`, an empty sequence gets spliced into the argument list.

Comment: +1, very nice answer. IIRC, one of the main motivating factors for introducing `Nothing` was to simplify this `If[...]` idiom and avoid using `Sequence` in such cases like this.